# mdc.snackbar.MDCSnackbar() throws this2.root_.querySelector is not a function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-component, material-components

I get the following error at the line where I create a new MDCSnackbar object in an angular component as thus:

`let snackbar = new mdc.snackbar.MDCSnackbar(document.getElementsByClassName('mdc-snackbar'))`.

The error stack is as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: *this2.root*.querySelector is not a function
>      
> at getActionButton (material-components-web.js:3144)
>      
> at Object.registerActionClickHandler (material-components-web.js:3174)
>      
> at MDCSnackbarFoundation.init (material-components-web.js:8572)
>      
> at MDCSnackbar.MDCComponent (material-components-web.js:587)
>      
> at new MDCSnackbar (material-components-web.js:3123)
>   at :1:11

I have the following html snippet for the snackbar:

```
<div class="mdc-snackbar"
 aria-live="assertive"
 aria-atomic="true"
 aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="mdc-snackbar__text"></div>
 <div class="mdc-snackbar__action-wrapper">
     <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-snackbar__action-button">
     </button>
</div>
```

A clue to what I may be doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the statement to `new mdc.snackbar.MDCSnackbar(document.querySelector('.mdc-snackbar')` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
var x = new mdc.snackbar.MDCSnackbar(document.querySelector('.mdc-snackbar'));
x.open();
```